# How to decode recursive JSON arrays in Haskell?

Tags: json, haskell

For such a piece of JSON:

```
[
  [
    "a",
    "b",
    [
      "c"
    ]
  ]
]
```

How to decode it in Haskell?

And this is a recursive array in JSON:

```
data CValue = CList [CValue] | CString String
```

I've read demos on parsing records with `JSON.text` and `Aeson`, but those code does not work on recursive data types.

Comment: There's the popular `aeson` library for turning JSON into Haskell types, either generically into a `Value` type representing plain JSON or deserialized into a custom type.

Comment: @bheklilr I did read some examples on `JSON.Text` and `Aeson` but all of them are showing showing how to decode records. While my question is how to decode a recursive JSON array.

Comment: `decode "[[\"a\",\"b\",[\"c\"]]]" :: Maybe Value` returns `Just (Array (fromList [Array (fromList [String "a",String "b",Array (fromList [String "c"])])]))`.  You can then pattern match on this like any other data type ([documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Value)].  You could write an instance for `FromJSON` where you just use `parseJSON` recursively [like this](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/079b06f21c02d5094d26).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something a little like this

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Traversable (traverse)
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Control.Applicative

data CValue = CList [CValue] | CString Text deriving Show

instance FromJSON CValue where
  parseJSON v = 
        withText "CString" (pure . CString) v
    <|> withArray "CList" (\a -> CList . toList <$> traverse parseJSON a) v
```

With this instance set you can use `decode :: FromJSON a => Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString -> Maybe a`

```
> decode "[[\"a\",\"b\",[\"c\"]]]" :: Maybe CValue
Just (CList [CList [CString "a",CString "b",CList [CString "c"]]])
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way can `Text.JSON` do this?

Comment: strange, `traverse p a` but what is `p`?

Comment: Oh, it was a copy and paste error, apologies. I've fixed `p` now.

Comment: I've actually honestly never used `Text.JSON`. I'm sure it is possible, but I'd have to go look up how.

Comment: Hi can you look at this too: `test.hs:7:40: Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Text’`?

Comment: Yup, sorry, it's a little nicer that way but unnecessary. Add `import Data.Text (Text)` to the top of the file.